# How to customise headerfragment of leanback library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, television, leanback

Is there a way to design a UI which is similar to **Gmail's TV android app**. Actually I'm new to TV development and looking for a way to design a UI which involves a vertical *sidebar with HeaderFragment* of *Leanback library*.